# Unity dll file delete file and write exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ioexception

I am trying to use file to read write my data and here is my code in dll file I written

```
public static void WriteFile(string fileName, string writeline)
{
    bool checker = false;
#if UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    checker = true;
#endif
    if (checker)
    {
        return;
    }
    string pathname = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName;
    if (File.Exists(pathname))
    {
        Debug.Log("userdata already exists.");
        File.Delete(pathname);
    }
    // Create the file.
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pathname))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(writeline);
        // Add some information to the file.
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }

}
```

And when I try to write file and this file exists this exception throws out,but if I write again there is no exception. I guess the file was deleted successfully at the first time I call this function.But I need to solve first time write file exception.

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path C:/Users/player/AppData/LocalLow/DefaultCompany/Testing Unity Project/UserInfo.txt
System.IO.File.Delete (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:179)
FileControl.WriteFile (System.String fileName, System.String writeline)
Test+<LoginClientTest>d__0.MoveNext ()
```

Comment: I guess no need to delete the file. `File.Create` overwrites the file if exists and not read-only. See doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @NeverHopeless I just tried but still got exception , and this time exception is on create
IOException: Sharing violation on path 

    FileControl.WriteFile (System.String fileName, System.String writeline)
    Test+<LoginClientTest>d__0.MoveNext ()

Comment: It's worth noting that deleting a file doesn't instantly delete the file, it sort of queues it up to be deleted, so when you run your write commands directly after in your code bloick, the target platform may not have yet actually deleted the file and released the lock on the filepath. This is why you get a 'Sharing violation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
// Exclude File.DeleteCode
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pathname))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(writeline);
    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    fs.Close();  // Close the stream
}
```

Or try writing file using `StreamWriter`.

[FileStream.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328800%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  I have tried fs.Close(); but still got Sharing violation on path exception on fs.Write , maybe I'll try FileStream.Close later.

Comment: There is another option of StreamWriter. look at that to.